# security find-identity lists an identity, but I can't find the identity in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, keychain, code-signing-certificate

I created an Apple Distribution Certificate with a `certSigningRequest` file per [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create):

> To manually generate a Certificate, you need a Certificate Signing
>   Request (CSR) file from your Mac. To create a CSR file, follow the
>   instructions below to create one using Keychain Access. Create a CSR
>   file.
>
> In the Applications folder on your Mac, open the Utilities folder and
>   launch Keychain Access.
>
> Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access >
>   Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate
>   Authority.
>
> ```
> In the Certificate Information window, enter the following information:
>     In the User Email Address field, enter your email address.
>     In the Common Name field, create a name for your private key (e.g., John Doe Dev Key).
>     The CA Email Address field should be left empty.
>     In the "Request is" group, select the "Saved to disk" option.
> Click Continue within Keychain Access to complete the CSR generating process.
> ```

I downloaded the public key as a `.cer` file from Apple. However, now, I can't find the certificate + key pair in `Keychain Access.app`. I would expect to see something like my Development certificate + key pair when selecting the `Certificates` `Category` under the `login` Keychain.

[image: Apple Development Certificate + Private Key pair under login->Certificates]

I do see a private key listed under `Keys` with the same name I included with my `.certSigningRequest`, but usually I can see a certificate beneath that as well, as in my development certificate below:

[image: Apple Development Private Key + Certificate pair under login->Keys]

I was able to find the identity from the command line with

```
$ security find-identity
Policy: X.509 Basic
  Matching identities
  1) WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW "iPhone Developer: Heath Borders (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  2) YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY "iPhone Distribution: Heath Borders (ZZZZZZZZZZ)"
     2 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW "iPhone Developer: Heath Borders (XXXXXXXXXX)"
  2) YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY "iPhone Distribution: Heath Borders (ZZZZZZZZZZ)"
     2 identities found
```

But if I search within a particular keychain, I can't find it:

```
$ security list-keychains
    "/Users/hborders/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
$ security find-identity /Users/hborders/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
    Policy: X.509 Basic
      Matching identities
      1) WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW "iPhone Developer: Heath Borders (XXXXXXXXXX)"
         1 identity found

      Valid identities only
      1) WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW "iPhone Developer: Heath Borders (XXXXXXXXXX)"
         1 identity found

$ security find-identity /Users/hborders/Library/Keychains//Library/Keychains/System.keychain
     0 valid identities found
```

Where is my certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, when I imported the `.cer` file I downloaded from Apple, `Keychain Access.app` imported the public key into the `System` keychain and the private key into my `login` keychain. Thus, searching exclusively within either `login` or `System` couldn't find the identity. Only the union of the two would yield a valid identity.

I moved the public key from the `System` keychain into the `login` keychain, and now everything works as expected.

Comment: Where you ever able to distinguish the keychain where the identities where found?

Comment: I clarified my answer. Does it make better sense now?

Comment: I meant with the security command. Often I only have access to my mac over ssh.

Comment: No, I was never able to determine the keychain of the public or private keys using `security find-identity`. However, I suspect you could do `security find-key` for the private key and `security find-certificate` for the public key on individual keychains, and that would probably let you determine the sources.